# How to align Column's children in different positions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to achieve the following design in Flutter?

I'm trying to position a Card and a Button within a Column.

The Card must be positioned centered in the Column wihtout taking into consideration the height of the Button.

And the Button must be positioned at the bottom of the Column.

[image: Design]

Comment: don't you want to use Stack ?

Comment: I'm new in Flutter. Do you think it is better to use Stack?

Comment: it will be easy using a stack.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how can I achieve the design I want?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is how you can do it using `Stack`

```
  Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 200.0,
              width: 200.0,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 10.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: MaterialButton(
                child: Text("Button"),
                color: Colors.grey,
                minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                onPressed: () => null,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

Answer (score 11):

To answer the question's title (aligning items in a "`Column`" widget), you can do it with the `Align` widget:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(...),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(...),
    ),
  ],
)
```